# user friendly url without filename in core php site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have a link **`www.example.com/folder/filename.php?cid=1&title=Chekcing`**

I want to make user friendly url from above link to : **`www.example.com/folder/1/Checking/`**

**I have an .htaccess code :**

```
**

    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\s [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?cid=([^&\s]+)\&title=([^&\s]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3? [R,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
    RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?cid=$2&title=$3[QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

**
```

But it only returns filename without .php : `**www.example.com/folder/filename/1/Checking**`

**I want to remove filename too, from the url...**

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Please anybody help me....ASAP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foldername/

#Remove .php extensions from php files :
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
#__________


#Redirect urls with query strings to cleaner version :
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /filename\.php\?cid=([^&]+)&title=([^\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [NC,R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ foldername/filename.php?cid=$1&title=$2 [QSA,L,NC]
#___________
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply...But it doesn't work well.... its output as : **www.example.com/Foldername/Foldername/1/Checking**,and showing Internal Server error

Comment: Is your htaccess in root folder of your site?

Comment: no...inside the folder...So I gave RewriteBase /Foldername/

Comment: Where is the **RewriteBase /foldername/** in your htaccess?

Comment: **RewriteBase /foldername/** is just after **RewriteEngine On**

Comment: Okay, I edited my answer, Reload the page to see changes

Comment: Can you please tell me how to avoid that Error 404

Comment: Deepash, As far as I think 404 error was because of bad rewrite path, please add the foldername to the last rewrite path, I had updated the answer yesterday , did you check it?